# Custom header support wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have tried many tutorials for custom header support but i am able to add up the support but i am not able to change header..Down here is Index.php

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header"><h1>Super Plain</h1></div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=');?>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
              <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
              <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div><!--/ #content -->

        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>News</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ornare sodales porta. Mauris laoreet tempor luctus. Nunc consequat </p>        
        </div><!--/ #sidebar -->  
    </div><!--/ #main -->

</div><!--/ #page -->
```

here is my css

```
#header{
        background-color:#c1d9c5;
        color:#405952;
        padding:55px;
}
#header h1{
        margin:0;
        font-size:72px;
        font-weight:normal;
}
```

and here is my function.php file

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'width'         => 980,`enter code here`
    'height'        => 60,
    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.jpg',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
?>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish. I understand that you are trying to make edits to the *header*, but what specific edits?

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to make edit to the header well i know i can change header from css but i want to provide this feature in my theme to the user so he can easily change the header by just uploading image

Answer (score 0):

Why you are try to enable custom header when you can change your header image easily by editing CSS stylesheet?

Comment: i know i can change it but i need to provide this custom header change feature in the wordpress theme that i have designed....so please help me out for this

Comment: yea, understood your need. So I suggest you to take a look at a simple wordpress theme with this feature and compare your codes with that. I don't think you can get help in this page.